# Is it possible to use an external SQL file in a Rails migration?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, migration

I have to create a Rails migration which creates many triggers and stored procedures.

Normally one would do that using the `execute` method, but because of the size of the statements, I'd rather keep them in an external file and reference it from the migration.

How can I do that? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just store them in a text file and read them in via a File object.

```
sql = ""
source = File.new("./sql/procedures.sql", "r")
while (line = source.gets)
  sql << line
end
source.close
execute sql
```

It's ugly, but works.  I'd strongly recommend keeping the stored procedures/triggers inside migrations for easy rollbacks.

If you do the "external file" method, you'll need to maintain two additional files per migration, one for adding all the stuff, and one for dropping in in case of a:

```
rake db:rollback
```

Comment: ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)

Answer (score 6):

I did the following where we needed:

```
class RawSqlMigration < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute File.read(File.expand_path('../../sql_migrations/file.sql', __FILE__))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Mike’s answer works without problems if you have only one statement in the file, but if there is more statements (multiple inserts and updates, for example), ActiveRecord will fail as it doesn’t support multiple statements with one call by default.

One solution would be to modify ActiveRecord to support multiple statements, as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13012564/345959).

Other solution would be to ensure that your SQL file contains only one statement per row and use a loop like

```
source = File.open "db/foo.sql", "r"
source.readlines.each do |line|
  line.strip!
  next if line.empty? # ensure that rows that contains newlines and nothing else does not get processed
  execute line
end
source.close
```