# ActiveRecord execute raw sql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I try create table with intermediate results specialy for report.
What I'm doing is:

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql_query)
```

sql_query is:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;

      DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _by_people_daily;

      CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _by_people_daily
      AS
      SELECT #{date_int} AS date_int,
             memberships.user_id AS user_id,
             ci.community_id,
             ci.content_id,
             contents.composite_type AS content_type,

             COUNT(views.id) AS views,
             COUNT(comments.id) AS comments,
             COUNT(shares.id) AS shares,
             COUNT(likes.id) AS likes,
             COUNT(uploads.id) AS uploads
      FROM community_items AS ci
        JOIN memberships ON memberships.community_id = ci.community_id
        JOIN contents ON ci.content_id = contents.id
        JOIN (SELECT '#{day_begin}' as start_date, '#{day_end}' as end_date) AS dates
        LEFT JOIN contents AS uploads
               ON uploads.id = ci.content_id
              AND uploads.user_id = memberships.user_id
              AND uploads.created_at BETWEEN dates.start_date AND dates.end_date
        LEFT JOIN comments
               ON comments.content_id = ci.content_id
              AND comments.user_id = memberships.user_id
              AND comments.created_at BETWEEN dates.start_date AND dates.end_date
        LEFT JOIN shares
               ON shares.content_id = ci.content_id
              AND shares.user_id = memberships.user_id
              AND shares.created_at BETWEEN dates.start_date AND dates.end_date
        LEFT JOIN likes
               ON likes.content_id = ci.content_id
              AND likes.user_id = memberships.user_id
              AND likes.created_at BETWEEN dates.start_date AND dates.end_date
        LEFT JOIN views
               ON views.viewable_id = ci.content_id
              AND views.viewable_type = 'Content'
              AND views.user_id = memberships.user_id
              AND views.created_at BETWEEN dates.start_date AND dates.end_date
      WHERE COALESCE(views.id, comments.id, shares.id, likes.id, uploads.id ) IS NOT NULL
        #{ " AND users.company_id = #{@company.id} " if @company }
      GROUP BY memberships.user_id, ci.community_id, ci.content_id, contents.composite_type ;

      DELETE FROM intermediate_by_people WHERE date_int = #{date_int} ;

      INSERT INTO intermediate_by_people
            (date_int, user_id, community_id, content_id, content_type, views, comments, shares, uploads, likes)
      SELECT date_int, user_id, community_id, content_id, content_type, views, comments, shares, uploads, likes
      FROM _by_people_daily ;
```

I'm getting error every time

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _by_people_daily;
```

But when I pass query to mysql client it working correctly.

What I'm doing wrong and how execute couple sql statements with ActiveRecord

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord's MySQL connection can only execute one statement by default. To execute multiple statements, `CLIENT_MULTI_STATEMENTS`(65536) need to be passed as an option when creating the connection. The code may look like this:

```
ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter.new(mysql, logger, [host, username, password, database, port, socket, 65536], config)
```

You can find `ConnectionAdapters::MysqlAdapter.new` in your mysql gem, and override that method in `config/initializers`.

Comment: Today you can pass array with `MULTI_STATEMENTS` to the `flags` option in `database.yml`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/43633321/338859

Answer (score 1):

Did you try escaping your query?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `_by_people_daily`
```

A table beginning with a underscore looks suspicious to me.

**Update:**

Look what I have found via google: http://www.seanr.ca/tech/?p=75

Comment: I rename table and try comment out some starements it does not help.